# Using Jackson XmlMapper to serialize to an XML DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, jackson

I know it's possible to serialize directly to a String using `XmlMapper.writeValueAsString()`, but I would like to serialize a DOM tree.  Either a new Document or, preferably, serialize directly to an existing DOM Node.  Can this be done with Jackson?

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the solution by using an `XMLStreamWriter`.

Try the following snippet:

```
XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
factory.createXMLStreamWriter(new DOMResult(yourNode));

XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
ToXmlGenerator xmlGenerator = mapper .getFactory().createGenerator(sw);
mapper.writerFor(YourClass.class).writeValue(xmlGenerator, yourInstance);
```